# Assign Custom classes to every Excerpt

Tags: php, customization, css, excerpt

I have Around 40 **Excerpts on my homepage** (I am using Gantry Framework) and I want to **style each of these Excerpts in a different Manner**. i.e Different Backgrounds, Font color For Every Excerpt.

So How can I **add custom Class to each and every excerpt** which is there on my homepage...say in manner Excerpt1 , Excerpt2 .... Excerpt40.

**This is what I have explored so far**: These Excerpts Are being called in a file content-blog.php like this!!

```
<div class="post-content">
  <?php if( $gantry->get( 'blog-content', 'content' ) == 'excerpt' ) : ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  <?php else : ?>
    <?php the_content( false ); ?>   
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

So If I do this:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <?php if( $gantry->get( 'blog-content', 'content' ) == 'excerpt' ) : ?>
      <div class="sameExcerpt">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      </div>
    <?php else : ?>
      <?php the_content( false ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

A single class i.e `sameexcerpt` will be assigned to each excerpt. But if can somehow use a global variable or static variable.

and keep incrementing that variable like this:

```
<div class="sameExcerpt<php echo ++globalvariable">
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>  
<?php else : ?>
  <?php the_content( false ); ?>     
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Then I think I can Assign a different Class to Every Excerpt.

Any Help Will Be greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there are syntax errors in your (last block of) code.

And secondly, you don't need to add any specific class at all. Just use the post ID for each post:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="post-content">
        <?php if ('excerpt' === $gantry->get('blog-content', 'content')) : ?>
            <div class="excerpt">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php the_content(false); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</article>
```

Then you can target your excerpts like so:

```
#post-23 .excerpt {
    /* styles for excertp of post 23 */
}

#post-42 .excerpt {
    /* styles for excertp of post 42 */
}
```

---

But, why would you want to individually target each and every excerpt in the first place?

This is unfeasible for a large number of posts.
And your website might look a little chaotic, too.

Comment: I have already tried '#post-312 .excerpt{  }' and '#post-312 {}', both of them are not working. I want to target only 10 excerpts  and i thought the only way out is to add custom classes to each and every excerpt!! Actually i want to show a few quotes on these excerpts , and i want to style each and every quotes in a different manner. It will look nice!

Comment: Http://www.lifathon.com

Comment: The above would be the only logical way within wordpress to do this, unless you where to create a function that randomly generates class names and contains 1 - 40 as an interger you could then append the two together.

Comment: There are several errors in your HTML. For instance, you should use `esc_attr` for your `title` attribute values. And the post with ID 312 doesn't even have an excerpt. Are you sure you are trying to target the right post, and/or added the above code at the right place?

Comment: I did some research on global variables ( We can declare them in file functions.php and use them in other files by declare global $variablename).'<div class="excerpt<?php echo $variablex ?>"> 
   <?php $variablex=$variablex+1; ?>' with the help of this i was able to assign a different classes like excerpt1, excerpt2 etc to each and every excerpt, But even now when i assign some css properties to these classes, its not rendering. The way that i add css is through my custom css plugin, or appearance editor, or directly modifying style.css files in theme folder. Which of them is the right way??

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys... It worked, There was some problem with css rendering...its working by the above method..Anyways i learned how to use global variables in wordpress because of this....thanks again..